# Error: -classpath requires class path specification

Tags: maven, cmd, windows-10, maven-2

I have installed Maven and I did all steps, but when I tried to execute it, I see in cmd this error -> Error: -classpath requires class path specification

My environment variables are these:

> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
>
> M2 C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\apache-maven\src\bin
>
> M2_HOME C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\apache-maven\src

You can see my Path here:

[image: Path]

And executable files are here:

[image: mvn files]

As you can see, maven files are in C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\apache-maven\src\bin so, for this reason, I have these environment variables. Likewise, I have tried with "standard" path from all the solution of Internet, but it doesn't work. (As standard I mean C:\apache-maven-3.5.2 and C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin)

What am I doing bad? If i change this path of evironment variables, I get a "can't recognize the command"

Thanks for all, waiting for your answers!

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

I downloaded source files from Maven and I should have downloaded binary files. With binary files and these environtment variables it works perfectly:

> JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4
>
> M2 C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin
>
> M2_HOME C:\apache-maven-3.5.2

Comment: was banging my head for quite some time and downloading the binary zip worked charm. Thanks

Comment: This solution helped. Needed to download binary

Answer (score 11):

WINDOWS USERS SOLUTION:

1. Downloaded the apache software from here: `https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi`. I chose the "Binary Zip Archive".
2. Unpack contents to your desired directory. My standard directory is `C:\Program Files` (after unpacking, the path to the bin folder should look like this --> `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin`
3. Create environmental variables: press windows button and pause button. Select "Advanced system settings". For User Variables create the following:

   Variable Name: `M2`     Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3`

   Variable Name: `M2_HOME` Variable Value: `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3`

For System Variable, select the existing "PATH" variable and select "Edit." Select "New" and type `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin`

Assuming you already have Java and JDK setup, go to Command Prompt in your computer and type `mvn -version`. It should show you the version information.

Comment: I had to restart my computer after following these steps as well

Answer (score 1):

First I assumed you already have Java and JDK setup, go to Command Prompt in your computer and check ***%JAVA_HOME%***

You have already download apache-maven-3.x.y.bin (I wrote this especially because of my problem with apache-maven-3.x.y.src). So, my first advice you should download binary files.

Now, you can go to ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES, and **add variable name M2_HOME**
                                          and **add variable name MAVEN_HOME**
with your maven directory, of course. Example: variable value: **c:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.x.y**

Now, you can test the variables on your Command Prompt like that:

```
echo %MAVEN_HOME%
echo %M2_HOME%
```

Then you have to set bin directory to your **PATH** variable on **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**. For System Variable inside the *ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES*, select the existing "PATH" variable, and select "Edit." Select "New" and type **%M2_HOME%\bin**

Another way using Command Prompt example: Add the bin directory to your PATH:

```
set PATH="%M2_HOME%\bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

Download `Binary archive` instead of `Source archive`.

Answer (score 0):

> In your System environment you have to set like this 
>   **variable:M2_HOME**        **value:C:\apache-maven-3.5.2**      then you have to set in variable path like this **%M2_HOME%\bin;** finally in your cmd administartor type **mvn -version**

Comment: Hi @A K, thanks for your answer but, If I do it, cmd says this: "mvn" is not recognized as an intern or extern command...
I modified M2_HOME as you said, M2 with %M2_HOME%\bin and Path with %M2_HOME%\bin. I said in question that I did it, but this answer doesn-t work for me :(

Comment: can you please share the path??

Comment: Here you have (with your changes):
 C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\TCS\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4;

Comment: I think so, how can I test it? If I put java on cmd it is reconigzed and, in fact, I can start my Tomcat Server which runs with JDK

Comment: please check in your cmd admin type java -version is it showing or not????

Comment: M2_HOME -> C:\apache-maven-3.5.2
But it throws a not recognized command

| If I use this -> C:\apache-maven-3.5.2\apache-maven\src
it throws the error of the title of this topic

Comment: ok..refer below link i thik its helpful for u  https://dev-pages.info/how-to-install-maven-on-windows-10/   and  https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Comment: I use mvn -version

Comment: mvn -v doesn't work. I'm reading your links but what I'm doing too is downloading another time maven. I downloaded source files, now I'm downloading binary files probably this is the problem (?)

Comment: yeah ok try to  download another maven zip...above functions working fine  my side ..try to fix it...

Comment: @A K I found the problem!!! My files were not OK. I downloaded source files and I shoud have downloaded binary files. I edit my question with the answer and I give you a positive vote for your effort trying to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you added the Maven source code\bin folder to PATH, you have to remove it.