# maven code-name one create-GUI-form - what's the correct class path specification?

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to Codename One and just starting a new project. I created a project from the Bare Bones Java app template and am trying to add a GUI form. I'm trying to follow the instructions in the Codename One Maven Developer Guide, but I can't seem to get the class name correct. Anything I try gives me an Error: -classpath requires classpath specification.

The package name for my project is com.rena.test.family, and the main class is MyFamily. I want to add a form called AddMember, so I tried running 'mvn cn1:create-gui-form com.rena.test.family.AddMember,"' and I tried without the quotation marks also. Both gave me the -classpath requires classpath specification error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in your maven installation/configuration unrelated to Codename One. See this [Error: -classpath requires class path specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49046775/error-classpath-requires-class-path-specification)